# Creating record constructors that check for schema in Clojure

Tags: validation, clojure, plumatic-schema

Hello fellow Clojurians,

it is known that Clojure's [defrecord](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord)s do not respect type hints and any type of data can be put in record fields. I am looking for a way to restrict the fields of records in Clojure.

I started experimenting with the `defrecord` call of [Prismatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema).

```
(require '[schema.core :as sc])
(sc/defrecord Item [size :- Long, colour  :- String])
```

Now calling `(->Item 1 2)` just returns a new `Item` instance despite the second argument is a number instead of a string. I want the constructor call to throw some exception.

I have tried the followings to turn on validation on record instantiation without success.

- adding `^:always-validate` metadata to the defrecord
- calling `(sc/set-fn-validation! true)`
- calling `(sc/with-fn-validation (->Item 1 1))`

Is it possible to turn on schema validation on constructor calls without writing custom constructors?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I remembered an answer I wrote to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/45578607

Comment: yes, that question is a good answer to this one and covered both plumatic/schema and spec, so I'll make this question redirect to it. ir @erdos doesn't find this useful I'm happy to un-dupe it.